# why is docker not responding to apache2 port 443 proxpass but fine on port 80?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, docker

I have an Azure VM which has an apache2 running with the following configuration,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName .com

        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:4003/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4003/
       
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName .com

        ProxyRequests On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:4003/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4003/
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/.ca-bundle
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The docker container running has this port mapping

```
0.0.0.0:4003->80/tcp, :::4003->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4004->443/tcp, :::4004->443/tcp
```

which is fine when traffic comes to the server through port 80, proxypass comes into play in Apache config and directs the traffic to 4003 which belongs to this container.

The problem is when I browse the website through HTTPS, there comes the problem, traffic passes through port 443 and is forwarded to 4003 again but this time the docker container does not respond, I am not sure what is going on, why on Apache port 80 is it working and why on port 443 does not?

Similar is the case with NGINX config, even now when I have mapped the ports differently for port 443.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name .com;

        #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4003;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    client_max_body_size 1024M;
    server_name .com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4004;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you make Apache *proxy* traffic to itself? That's ... strange. Anyway. `127.0.0.1` is the VM, not the docker image. 127.0.0.1:4003 is not listening, 127.0.0.1:80 is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer vidarlo, I didn't understand your comment, can you please elaborate what mistake I am making here? When traffic comes through NGINX/APACHE through port 80 it is proxied to 4003, same is the case with when traffic comes on 443 in NGINX/APACHE,

Comment: 4003 is the mapping for the docker container.

Comment: And what's listening on port 4003?

Comment: The docker container port which is 80,

Comment: The whole point is why on VM's port 80 the proxy works like here proxy_pass http://localhost:4003; but does not on VM's port 443,

Comment: I have no idea what you're attempting to achieve here.

Comment: What is the exact error message you encounter when you try to access the server via https?

Comment: No error message, a blank page, meaning no response from the docker container inside the VM,

Comment: What does your logs show? Normally Apache will return 502 if upstream didn't answer...

Comment: Use a text based client for your tests (wget -S, curl) and provide the complete output.